# Getting `Long cannot be converted to Example<S>` in Spring 5 JPA findOne()

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm getting an `argument mismatch; Long cannot be converted to Example<S>` on the findOne call in the code below:

```
public Optional<AuditEvent> find(Long id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(persistenceAuditEventRepository.findOne(id))
        .map(auditEventConverter::convertToAuditEvent);
}
```

The above code is being converted to Spring 5 and Spring Boot 2.  It works fine in the original Spring 4 and Spring Boot 1 application.

Any ideas what I need to convert the above code to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of Spring 5 and Spring data JPA 2.0.0.M3 , I could see `findOne` method is removed in **CrudRepository** to the one in **QueryByExampleExecutor** 
so it is better to change  to `Optional<T> findById(ID arg0);` instead of `findOne` method 
Please find below :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S arg0);

    <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> arg0);

    Optional<T> findById(ID arg0);

    boolean existsById(ID arg0);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> arg0);

    long count();

    void deleteById(ID arg0);

    void delete(T arg0);

    void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> arg0);

    void deleteAll();
}
```

**QueryByExampleExecutor**:

```
public abstract interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
    public abstract <S extends T> S findOne(Example<S> paramExample);

    public abstract <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> paramExample);

    public abstract <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> paramExample, Sort paramSort);

    public abstract <S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> paramExample, Pageable paramPageable);

    public abstract <S extends T> long count(Example<S> paramExample);

    public abstract <S extends T> boolean exists(Example<S> paramExample);
}
```

Check docs on QueryForExampleExecutor :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getOne() instead of findOne()